# Trying to understand the breaking down of the complexified tangent space

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-geometry, almost-complex

I am reading some notes on the complexified tangent space. I don't understand how do we arrive at that $V^{(1,0)} = \{ X - iJX : X \in V\}$. 
I mean in one direction we have $JZ = J( v \otimes \alpha) = Jv \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \alpha$. In the other direction we have $iZ = i (v \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \alpha) = v \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} i\alpha$. Why is this the same as $X - iJX$ for $X \in V$.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that each vector in $V_{\mathbb C}$ can be written uniquely as $X\otimes 1 + Y\otimes i$, for some $X,Y\in V$. Given $Z = X\otimes1 + Y\otimes i$ with $JZ = iZ$, we have
$$
JX\otimes 1 + JY\otimes i = JZ = iZ = -Y\otimes1 + X\otimes i.
$$
By the uniqueness of the representation we conclude $JX = -Y$ (and $JY = X$). Therefore, $Z = X\otimes1 - JX\otimes i$ (for some $X\in V$).

Conversely, given a vector of the form $Z = X\otimes 1 - JX\otimes i$, for some $X\in X$, we have
$$
JZ = JX\otimes 1 -J^2X\otimes i = JX\otimes1 + X\otimes i = i\cdot (X\otimes 1 - JX\otimes i) = iZ.
$$

Comment: That is very clear. Can you just explain what do you mean by uniqueness of the representation ?

Comment: It means that given $X,X',Y,Y'\in V$ with $X\otimes1 + Y\otimes i = X'\otimes 1 + Y'\otimes i$ it follows that $X=X'$ and $Y=Y'$.

Comment: Given $Z\in V_{\mathbb C}$ and $X,Y\in V$ with $Z = X\otimes 1 + Y\otimes i$, I call $X\otimes1 + Y\otimes i$ a representation of $Z$.